# TensorFlow, what does the tensorflow_datasets.load() exactly return?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following a tutorial of TensorFlow ML and I am new to Python. I come from a background of languages like Java. Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l06c03_exercise_flowers_with_transfer_learning_solution.ipynb#scrollTo=DrIUV3V0xDL_) to the tutorial.

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Download the Flowers Dataset using TensorFlow Datasets
(training_set, validation_set), dataset_info = tfds.load(
    'tf_flowers',
    split=['train[:70%]', 'train[70%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
)

for example in training_set:
  num_training_examples += 1

# Reformat Images and Create Batches
IMAGE_RES = 224

def format_image(image, label):
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMAGE_RES, IMAGE_RES))/255.0
  return image, label

BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_batches = training_set.shuffle(num_training_examples//4).map(format_image).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(1)

validation_batches = validation_set.map(format_image).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(1)
```

I don't understand how this code operates: `(training_set, validation_set), dataset_info = tfds.load`. The function `tfds.load` downloads images of flowers. How come that `training_set` is iterable like some sort of array, when it should be a folder perhaps?

```
for example in training_set:
  num_training_examples += 1
```

Also how come each element in it is used in the following line as two arguments to the function `format_image(image, label)` in this line:

```
train_batches = training_set.shuffle(num_training_examples//4).map(format_image).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(1)
```

What is `training_set` exactly? Why is it not a folder that contains the following structure:

- flowers_a

  - file1, file2, file3 ... etc
- flowers_b

  - file1, file2, file3 ... etc
- flowers_c

  - file1, file2, file3 ... etc
- etc ...

instead its some sort of an array with each element containing an image and its label? It is not clear in the documentation what is happening for a beginner in Python such as I.

Comment: "It is not clear in the documentation ..." - It says very clearly what [load](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load#returns) returns in the docs. And it does not say anything about returning a folder or a folder structure.

Comment: it does create a folder, unless you specify `download=false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the name suggests, Tensorflow exists to "make the tensors flow". It's an entire ecosystem with data loading, preprocessing, and machine learning capabilities. So it's not built as an intuitive library that deals with `numpy` arrays. Tensorflow doesn't keep everything in memory so what `TFDS` returns is literally a "Tensorflow Dataset". You need to manipulate it as such. This means that you can't get basic information, like the count, intuitively. You need to iterate through the whole thing. For instance this line you gave:

```
for example in training_set:
  num_training_examples += 1
```

It's passing all the samples and counting them. For this part:

```
(training_set, validation_set), dataset_info = tfds.load...
```

It loads the "Tensorflow Dataset" as supervised, meaning that it's 2 tuples for data and label. If you remove the `as_supervised=True`, it will be a dictionary, and you can iterate through them with `dataset['image']` and `dataset['label']`.

Let me know if you want me to explain anything else.